# Nifi Processor splittext escape character

Tags: apache-nifi

I use splitText processor to split a multiple statement hql file into single hql statements on semicolon before sending them to PutHiveQL Processor 
'
My problem is that need to concat som fields and seperate them with ; meaning that i want splittext to ignore that particular semicolon. 
I tried to escape with

example.

```
drop table my table if exits;
create external table mytable as 
select CONCAT_WS('\;\',field1,field2.field3) as concatfields
from oldtable;
```

Now this will result in followidng statements

flowfile1

```
drop table my table if exits;
```

flowfile2

```
create external table mytable as 
select CONCAT_WS('\;
```

flowfile3

```
\',field1,field2.field3) as concatfields
from oldtable;
```

But clearly i want to escape my semicolon in CONCAT_WS('\;\',field1,field2.field3) as concatfields

is that possible ?

Comment: Im on HDF 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SplitContent? I thought SplitText only split on line boundaries. If you use SplitContent you should be able to split on ;\n (use Shift+Enter to input a newline character) and choose Keep Byte Sequence. This should split when a semicolon ends a line but keep your escaped semicolon intact.